# Couldn't connect to database - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to connect to my 000webhost MySQL database but it can't connect

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli("mysql9.000webhost.com", "a9012103_msg", "msg123", "a9012103_msg");

if($db->connect_error) {
  die("Couldn't connect to DB");
} else {
  die("Connection successful");
}
?>
```

I have all of the correct information. Here is the information for the database

***MySQL Database*** --- ***MySQL User*** --- ***MySQL Host***

a9012103_msg --- a9012103_msg --- mysql9.000webhost.com

I assume that the database automatically adds in the user after I create it. I have tried using localhost but that doesn't work either.

My website is [devconnect.comxa.com](http://devconnect.comxa.com)

Comment: It looks like your PHP page is hosted on the same machine as well. Have you tried changing ```mysql9.000webhost.com``` to ```localhost```?

I am pretty sure 000webhost would not expose a MySQL DB to the public internet like that, which is why you are probably not able to connect.

Comment: @kkaosninja If that were the case, they'd need to pay for using remote access.

Comment: `"mysql9.000webhost.com "` there's a space in there, get rid of it. If that's the real problem, the question's off-topic and a bad one at that.

Comment: See my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a blank space after the hostname:

"mysql9.000webhost.com "

Comment: you shouldn't go after off-topic typo questions. I've already addressed it in comments.

Comment: Ok. I could not because I have not enough reputation to add a comment.